# Spring 3 + Hibernate: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Cannot add or update a child row (ManyToMany)

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring

I am having problem with storing an Account item after editing. The Account item contains a Set of Roles (`@ManyToMany`). If i load the Account item and try to edit it everything works fine, until I try to add new Roles. The Roles are all presented with checkboxes. The ones that where originally checked are also checked in the edit form. If I now try to check some others too and try to save the changed Account, I get an exception from Hibernate, saying:

> java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`fi_mc-tool`.`account_role`, CONSTRAINT `FK4AC9CB881F90989D` FOREIGN KEY (`Account_id`) REFERENCES `Account` (`id`))

In the Role Entity I have not defined any relationship to Account. Its just defined on the Account Entity. Might this be the cause?

**Extract of Account Entity:**

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "Account_Role", joinColumns = { 
    @JoinColumn(name = "Account_id") }, 
    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "Role_id") })
private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<Role>(0);
```

**Extract of Account Service:**

```
@Transactional
public void merge(Account account) {
    accountDAO.merge(account);
}
```

**Extract of Account DAO:**

```
public void merge(Account account) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().merge(account);
}
```

**Extract of edit.jsp of Account**

```
    <tr>
        <td style="width:75px">
            <label for="roles"><spring:message code="labels.account.form.roles" text="Roles" /></label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <form:checkboxes path="roles" items="${roleList}" itemLabel="name" itemValue="idAsString" delimiter="<br/>"/> 
        </td>

</tr>
```

**Extract of Account Controller**

```
/**
 * edit() - Save edited item
 * @param id of changed object
 * @param item which has been changed
 * @return  path to view
 */
@RequestMapping(value="/edit/{id}", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String edit(@PathVariable("id") Long id, @ModelAttribute("item") Account item, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
    accountService.merge(item);

    return "redirect:/account/list";
}

/**
 * edit() - Edit an item
 * @param id of item to change
 * @param model to store item
 * @return  path to view
 */
@RequestMapping(value="/edit/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String editForm(@PathVariable("id") Long id, Model model) {
    Account item = accountService.load(id);

    for(Role r : item.getRoles()){
        System.out.println("ROLE ITEM: ID="+r.getId()+" | NAME="+r.getName()+" | HASH="+r);
    }

    for(Role r : roleService.list()){
        System.out.println("ROLE SERVICE: ID="+r.getId()+" | NAME="+r.getName()+" | HASH="+r);
    }

    model.addAttribute("item", item);
    model.addAttribute("roleList", roleService.list());

    return "account/edit";
}
```

**Extract from spring-servlet.xml:**

```
<!-- Activates various annotations to be detected in bean classes -->
<context:annotation-config />

<!-- Scans the classpath for annotated components that will be auto-registered as Spring beans -->
<context:component-scan base-package="fi.java.elearning.*" />

<!-- Configures the annotation-driven Spring MVC Controller programming model -->
<mvc:annotation-driven /> 

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!-- Include Tiles for View Rendering -->
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass">
        <value>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/configurations/tiles/tiles.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- multipart file resolver bean -->
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"/>   


<!-- multi language support -->

<bean id="localeResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="de" />
</bean>

<bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
    <property name="paramName" value="language" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping" >
    <property name="interceptors">
       <list>
        <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
       </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="languages/messages" />
</bean>

<!-- Import Hibernate Context -->
<import resource="configurations/hibernate/hibernate-context.xml" />

<!-- Import Spring Security -->
<import resource="configurations/spring/spring-security.xml" />
```

**Extract from web.xml:**

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<filter>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<error-page>
  <error-code>404</error-code>
  <location>/WEB-INF/views/contents/exceptions/404.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

**Extract from hibernate.context.xml:**

```
<context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/configurations/hibernate/database.properties" />

<!-- Declare the Hibernate SessionFactory for retrieving Hibernate sessions -->
<!-- See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/annotation/AnnotationSessionFactoryBean.html -->                           
<!-- See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/index.html?org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html -->
<!-- See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/index.html?org/hibernate/Session.html -->
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean"
             p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
             p:configLocation="${hibernate.config}"
             p:packagesToScan="fi.java.elearning"/>

<!-- Declare a datasource that has pooling capabilities-->   
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
            destroy-method="close"
            p:driverClass="${app.jdbc.driverClassName}"
            p:jdbcUrl="${app.jdbc.url}"
            p:user="${app.jdbc.username}"
            p:password="${app.jdbc.password}"
            p:acquireIncrement="5"
            p:idleConnectionTestPeriod="60"
            p:maxPoolSize="100"
            p:maxStatements="50"
            p:minPoolSize="10" />

<!-- Declare a transaction manager-->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager" 
            p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory" />

<!-- Enable annotation style of managing transactions -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

Comment: @JoinColumn(name = "Account_id") }, 
    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "Role_id") })
actually defines the accont_id column.

Comment: Hi...i dont get you? Is this the Problem? If yes, how can I solve it? Thanks for your help...